# How can i revoke a setTimeout variable from an iframe (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child, parent, children

I have a problem about setTimeout and clearTimeout:
in index.php:

```
enter code here
dateVar  = new Date();
timer = setTimeout(function() {MyFuncFirst();}, 10000);
$(document).click(function(e)
                        {
                          clearTimeout(timer);
                          timer = setTimeout(function() {MyFuncNext();}, 10000);
                         });
```

Than i want to use clearTimeout in iframe in myframe.php :

```
clearTimeout(parent.timer);
```

i couldn't
but, this same code is running

```
parent.dateVar = new Date();
```

Why is this happening? How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can't interact with variables within an iFrame. The page loaded inside the iFrame is a completely separate page.

To overcome this you might want to look into AJAX to talk between the two pages, just like you would do between two websites.

Comment: "You can't interact with variables within an iFrame." You can [under certain conditions](https://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Same-origin_policy_for_DOM_access).

Comment: @PleaseStand Well there you go. I wouldn't suggest using it, but good find.

Answer (score 1):

Each `Window` object has its own "list of active timers" (see [the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#timers)). So try this:

```
parent.clearTimeout(parent.timer);
```